# Set initial default value in Angularjs dynamic selector

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

Does anyone know how to set up an initial default option in an Angularjs Select?

"myMapByCmd" below is a

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>
```

and so the "value" in item as item for item in value track by $index" is a `List<String>`.
If I put "Select value" first in the List from the back end, the selector initially shows/selects the last item in the list.

Man there must be a simple way to do this (Damn Angular is so fiddelly !)

```
        <table> 
                        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in myMapByCmd">
                        <td><label>{{key}} Title:</label></td>

                        <td>
                            <select name="my_val_sel"
                                    ng-init="mycommand.myValue[$index] = value[0]"
                                    ng-model="mycommand.myValue[$index]"
                                    ng-options="item as item for item in value track by $index"                                     
                                    ng-change="changeMyValue()">
                            </select>
                        </td>               
                    </tr>    
            </table>
```

if I do this it shows last and unselected...

```
     <select name="my_val_sel" ng-model="mycommand.myValue[$index]"
     ng-options="item as item for item in value track by $index" 
    ng-change="changeMyValue()">
  <option value="" ng-selected="selected">FACK</option>
 </select>
```

the myMapByCmd JSON looks like:
     {
      "ONE": [
     "my-one",
     "my-two",
     "my-three"
      ]
     }

Thanks!

Comment: Add a option tag inside select attribute.. I.e <select ....> <option value=""> Select value</option> </select>

Comment: if I do it shows last and unselected...                                    <select name="aid_val_sel"
            ng-model="tl1command.aidValue[$index]"
            ng-options="item as item for item in value track by $index"             
             ng-change="changeAidValue()">
            <option value="" ng-selected="selected">FACK</option>
        </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on data its using, I have created demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/wjs0g3pu/). If format of data is same and you are looking for similar result then there is no need to use track by $index.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table> 
                        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in myMapByCmd">
                        <td><label>{{key}} Title:</label></td>

                        <td>
                            <select name="my_val_sel"
                                    ng-init="mycommand.myValue[$index] = value[0]"
                                    ng-model="mycommand.myValue[$index]"
                                    ng-options="item as item for item in value"   
                                    ng-change="changeMyValue()">
                            </select>
                        </td>               
                    </tr>    
            </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.myMapByCmd = { "ONE": [ "my-one", "my-two", "my-three" ],                                              
                        "TWO": [ "my-one", "my-two", "my-three" ],
                        "THREE": [ "my-one", "my-two", "my-three" ]}
}]);
```

Comment: Congratulations !  You're the winner :)   That's what worked. I load the first option as a default and ng-init selects it as above.  Thanks a million !

Comment: I am glad that I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty value options inside select element. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aravinthan93/y08usjdc/1/)

```
 <select ng-options="...">
     <option value="">Select Value</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work the select fills and the last item is selected with "Select Value" at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, this is what I use:

```
<select
    ng-model="record.id"
    ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in page_list"
>
     <option ng-show="record.id == 0" 
          value="">-- Choose Page --
     </option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ljbrown238/vaapo3ag/)

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete solution.  Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ljbrown238/vaapo3ag/).  Note that using this solution keeps the "Choose Page" from appearing again after an item has been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Future readers try this

```
<select ng-model="sel.myvar" ng-options="opt.label for opt in sel.myoptions">
    <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
</select>
```

For more details , please refer [here](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angularjs-adding-user-friendly-default-option-ng-options).